# (Proof Verification) Prove There Is A Hamiltonian Cycle for Every $n$ dimensional hypercube where $n\geq2$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

Prove There Is A Hamiltonian Cycle for Every $n$ dimensional hypercube where $n\geq2$

My book gave a very fancy proof by induction, but to me it seems obvious that if we simply follow the standard "1-bit flip" progression of Gray Code for $n$ bits we will get our answer because the first and last entries of this sequence are always connected in a hypercube, which would complete our cycle. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: I think that's fine, but you still would need to prove the Gray code works (e.g., that the first sequence and last sequence are adjacent) , which probably wouldn't be so much easier than the direct proof given in the book. If you want to have some fun, try proving that not only is the hypercube Hamiltonian, but that removing any set of $n-2$ edges results in a graph in which every edge is on a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: Your reasoning is just correct, I am interested to know how fancy the proof of your book is, perhaps it just works with the same principle...

Comment: Also is the proof really that fancy? If $Q_{n-1}$ is Hamiltonian, then take a Hamilton cycle on vertices $b_1,\ldots,b_{2^{n-1}}$. Then appending $1$ in front of each $b_i$ or $0$ in front of each $b_i$ gives two cycles  $C_1$ and $C_0$ respectively in $Q_n$ of length $2^{n-1}$ covering every vertex. Now the vertices $(0,b_1)$, $(0,b_2)$,$(1,b_2)$,$(1,b_1)$ form a $4$-cycle in $Q_n$. Then deleting edges $[(0,b_1),(0,b_2)]$ and $[(1,b_1),(1,b_2)]$ from $C_0$ and $C_1$, and then adding edges $[(0,b_1),(1,b_1)]$ and $[(0,b_2),(1,b_2)]$ produces a Hamilton cycle in $Q_n$.

Comment: @SolomonLo it's the same proof that Casteels gives above

Comment: I ask whether there can be some proof other than induction or flipping, because I think probably all Hamiltonian path in hypercube can be obtained by automorphism, just guessing.